# Openness of $(0,1)$ with non-standard topology on $X$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am unsure whether there is a mistake or omission in my professor's lecture notes or if I am not seeing the big picture.

He first defines openness in a general metric space like this:

> A subset $U \subset X$ is open if for all $x \in U$, $\exists \epsilon > 0$ such that $\forall y \in X$, $d(x,y) < \epsilon$ implies $y \in U$.

This definition makes sense to me. In the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$, it means that we can find an open ball around any point in the set that is entirely contained within. I cannot quite visual what this mean for other metrics, but this is certainly an (appropriately) more general definition.

My professor than asserts that $(0,1)$ is open and $[0,1]$ is closed. In $\mathbb{R}$ under the usual topology, this makes perfect sense and is easy to prove. But the metric space is not defined, nor is the metric, so I do not know how to even begin to prove this fact.

Am I correct that we need to define the space and the topology? Does it not matter because $(0,1)$ is open in any topology $X$ that contains $\mathbb{R}$? Is the same true for any such metric $d$?

Comment: Your professor was talking about the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$, not an arbitrary topology.

Comment: I thought so. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual topology is that induced by the metric defined by $d(x,y)=|x-y|$.

Incidentally, $(0,1)$ is not open in some possible topologies on $\Bbb R$.  One easy example is the *trivial topology*, in which the only open sets are $\Bbb R$ and $\emptyset$.

Comment: The phrasing "$(0,1)$ is not open in _every_ topology on $\mathbb{R}$" may be preferable to the current one, "not open on any topology". The latter has the possible reading that $(0,1)$ is never open, which may confuse beginners. You could even consider "not open in some possible topologies".

Comment: Thanks for catching that.  I know I occasionally put my foot in my mouth ever so slightly.  As you intimated, a non-beginner would probably understand, from the context.  I noticed you are in England, where they may have better command of the language. @Z.A.K.